# What are the knowledge I should have before creating a Debian package? Does it require high knowledge on Shell programming?

Tags: packaging, debian

What should I learn to create a deb package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Without you explaining more, the only thing you *need* is a control file inside a DEBIAN folder with the right permissions.
Here's everything, from which you can pick and choose what you need: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/

```
$ ls -R mypkg
mypkg:
DEBIAN

mypkg/DEBIAN:
control
$ cat mypkg/DEBIAN/control 
Package: mypackage
Version: 1.0
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Me
Description: This is a test package which provides nothing.

$ dpkg -b mypkg/ mypackage_1.0_all.deb
dpkg-deb: building package `mypackage' in `mypackage_1.0_all.deb'.

$ sudo dpkg -i mypackage_1.0_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package mypackage.
(Reading database ... 364918 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mypackage_1.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking mypackage (1.0) ...
Setting up mypackage (1.0) ...
```

Comment: I have to create a Debian package that will include a group of apps like soliatre, sudoku etc how do I bind them?

Comment: @user464180 What do you mean by bind? If you just want to include the apps in your package, you need to construct the directory structure you'd like in the same directory which contains the DEBIAN folder. This might look like /usr/bin/solitare /usr/bin/sudoku for the binaries, and with required libs perhaps in /usr/lib.